# Split long algorithm (store IF and ELSE structure)

Tags: page-breaking, algorithmicx

I have a long algorithm that I would like to split in two pages. Something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}  

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{function}\label{function}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Function{function}{}
    \State $x \gets y$;
    \While{$x < y$}
        \If{$x = y$}
            \State $split \gets split$; %%SPLIT HERE
        \ElsIf{$x = y$} 
            \State $x \gets y$;
        \ElsIf{$x < y$} 
            \State $x \gets y$;
            \State $x \gets y$;  
        \Else 
            \State $x \gets y$;
            \State $x \gets y$;
        \EndIf
    \EndWhile
    \If{$x = y$}
          \If{$x = y$}
              \State $x \gets y$;
          \ElsIf{$x = y$}
              \State $x \gets y$;
          \ElsIf{$x <= y$}
              \State $x \gets y$;
              \State $x \gets y$;
          \Else
              \State $x \gets y$;
              \State $x \gets y$;
          \EndIf
    \ElsIf{$x = y$}
        \State $x \gets y$;
    \EndIf
    \State \Return $x$
\EndFunction
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

I found a solution using `\algstore`, however this does not work when placed in IF-ELSE structure. I have read something about `\vsplit` - but I am not sure how to use it to split my code.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please add a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Answer (score 4):

Don't use an `algorithm` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}  

\begin{document}

\section{Function}\label{function}

\begin{algorithmic}[1] \Function{function}{}
    \State $x \gets y$;
    \While{$x < y$}
        \If{$x = y$}
            \State $split \gets split$; %%SPLIT HERE
        \ElsIf{$x = y$} 
            \State $x \gets y$;
        \ElsIf{$x < y$} 
            \State $x \gets y$;
            \State $x \gets y$;  
        \Else 
            \State $x \gets y$;
            \State $x \gets y$;
        \EndIf
    \EndWhile
    \While{$x < y$}
        \If{$x = y$}
            \State $split \gets split$; %%SPLIT HERE
        \ElsIf{$x = y$} 
            \State $x \gets y$;
        \ElsIf{$x < y$} 
            \State $x \gets y$;
            \State $x \gets y$;  
        \Else 
            \State $x \gets y$;
            \State $x \gets y$;
        \EndIf
    \EndWhile
    \While{$x < y$}
        \If{$x = y$}
            \State $split \gets split$; %%SPLIT HERE
        \ElsIf{$x = y$} 
            \State $x \gets y$;
        \ElsIf{$x < y$} 
            \State $x \gets y$;
            \State $x \gets y$;  
        \Else 
            \State $x \gets y$;
            \State $x \gets y$;
        \EndIf
    \EndWhile
    \While{$x < y$}
        \If{$x = y$}
            \State $split \gets split$; %%SPLIT HERE
        \ElsIf{$x = y$} 
            \State $x \gets y$;
        \ElsIf{$x < y$} 
            \State $x \gets y$;
            \State $x \gets y$;  
        \Else 
            \State $x \gets y$;
            \State $x \gets y$;
        \EndIf
    \EndWhile
    \If{$x = y$}
          \If{$x = y$}
              \State $x \gets y$;
          \ElsIf{$x = y$}
              \State $x \gets y$;
          \ElsIf{$x <= y$}
              \State $x \gets y$;
              \State $x \gets y$;
          \Else
              \State $x \gets y$;
              \State $x \gets y$;
          \EndIf
    \ElsIf{$x = y$}
        \State $x \gets y$;
    \EndIf
    \State \Return $x$
\EndFunction
\end{algorithmic}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: May I ask, why do you say, "Don't use an `algorithm` environment"?